# InsertAt() method doesn't update SQL table

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I use this line:

```
DataSet.SomeTableName.Rows.InsertAt(someRow, 0);
```

After this line I update my SQL table.
But the inserted row does not appear on the SQL server side.

Any idea why the inserted row doesn't appear on the SQL server side?

Comment: How do you update the SQL table?

Comment: did you see the rows get added into Dataset?

Comment: Updating the table (AcceptChanges) and updating SQL Server with the values from the table (i.e. via a data adapter) are different. Can you provide more code, specifically the code handling your "update"?

Comment: connected or disconnected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue the `SetAdded` method:

```
someRow.AcceptChanges();
someRow.SetAdded();
```

as far as I know `InsertAt` doesn't actually perform the `RowState` modifications.